# Converting a timestamp into more readable format in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm starting off with something that looks like this: 
1397773800000

I convert it into something more readable with this:

```
var time = 1397773800000;
var date = new Date(time);
alert(date); //Thu Apr 17 2014 18:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

However, I want it to be even *more* readable. I want it to say Thursday, April 17th at 4:30pm EST, for example. And I'm not sure how to separate out each of those components using javascript.

Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4Nbk/

UPDATE: I'm trying out moment.js thanks to a responder, but I can't get it to work in a test JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/w4Nbk/2/

UPDATE #2: Never mind, got it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/yS4da/637/
Could just be that moment.js wasn't called correctly in the fiddle.

Comment: Where "more readable" is subjective. The proposed string has no year and *EST* is an abbreviation that is used for at least 3 different time zones (and is different to the one in the OP). :-)

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend you check out [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

It's the perfect tool for all things related to dates and times!

---

```
var time = 1397773800000;

moment(time).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
moment(time).format('dddd');
moment(time).format("MMM Do YY");
moment(time).format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');
moment(time).format();
```

Output

```
April 17th 2014, 5:30:00 pm
Thursday
Apr 17th 14
2014 escaped 2014
2014-04-17T17:30:00-05:00
```

Comment: Sorry, do you know why this isn't working in my JSFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/w4Nbk/2/